# Not being together arrangement exercise

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have these 2 exercises, i tried to solve them but i'm now sure about my answer. I'm not really good at this mathematics area, so i'd appreciate any help

**Exercise 1.-** "Rex is going to paint a six-floor building and he has 2 colors, green and blue. How many ways can the building be painted, if each floor is painted in a single color and there can't be consecutive floors painted blue?" *Note: He can't paint all the building Green.*

**My ideas**

I solved it in a "manual" way. Let's see, if Rex just paint one floor blue, he can paint the building of 6 ways,that are:

1. B,G,G,G,G,G
2. G,B,G,G,G,G
3. G,G,B,G,G,G
4. G,G,G,B,G,G
5. G,G,G,G,B,G
6. G,G,G,G,G,B

if he paint 2 floors blue, he can do it of 10 ways :

1. B,G,B,G,G,G
2. B,G,G,B,G,G
3. B,G,G,G,B,G
4. B,G,G,G,G,B
5. G,B,G,B,G,G
6. G,B,G,G,B,G
7. G,B,G,G,G,B
8. G,G,B,G,B,G
9. G,G,B,G,G,B
10. G,G,G,B,G,B

and if he paint 3 floors, he can do it of 4 ways.

1. B,G,B,G,B,G
2. B,G,B,G,G,B
3. B,G,G,B,G,B
4. G,B,G,B,G,B

in total he got 6 + 10 + 4 = 20 ways

But i don't really want that, i'd like to do it in a "formula way", with a Binomial coefficient, or by a permutation/combination. i got:

*painting 1 floor blue he has:*

$\frac{6!}{1!5!}$ = 6

*Painting 2 floors blue he has (The total ways to paint two floors minus the ways to paint consecutive floors:*

$\frac{6!}{2!4!}$ - $\frac{5!}{1!4!}$ = $15-5$ = $10$

Next to that i don't really know how. I would appreciate for any help, thanks.

Comment: Let $f(n)$ denote the number of ways to paint $n$ floors; show that $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$ if $n\ge2$. These will be Fibonacci numbers, and for six floors there should be 21 ways, not 20.

Comment: You might want to create two posts: one for each problem...

Comment: @Tad Slightly incorrect given the condition "*he can't paint all as green*".  These will be one less than fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks - I should read more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's paint the building floor by floor, and keep track of two numbers: options where the top-most painted floor (floor $n$) is green $g(n)$, and those where it is blue $b(n)$.

Clearly $g(1)=1$ and $b(1)=1$ (ignoring, for now, the restriction on an all-green building).

If we have painted up to floor $k$, how many options are there for floor $k\!+\!1$? To paint the new floor blue, we need the previous floor green, so $b(k\!+\!1)=g(k)$. But we don't have that restriction on green floors, so $g(k\!+\!1) = g(k)+b(k)$.

So we can quickly paint up the building:

\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
\text{floor }n & g(n) & b(n) \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 2 \\ \hline
4 & 5 & 3 \\ \hline
5 & 8 & 5 \\ \hline
6 & 13 & 8 \\ \hline
\end{array}

-then add these two and subtract the all-green option to get the answer of $13+8-1 = 20$

On the way to the answer, most people with an interest in mathematics will recognize the Fibonacci sequence, and it's clear that $g(k\!+\!1) = g(k)+g(k\!-\!1)$ (since $b(k)=g(k\!-\!1)$) which explains this occurrence.